# I want to update a group of model object but it doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to assign these to users and using a form for the same model to update it but it doesn't work for some reason, this is the code

```
def assign_blanks(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = assign_blank_form(data=request.POST)
        from_value = request.POST.get("from_value", "")
        to_value = request.POST.get("to_value", "")
        blanks = blank.objects.all()
        for b in blanks:
            if b.number >= int(from_value) and b.number >= int(to_value):
                b.advisor = form.instance.advisor
                print(b.number)
        return render(request, 'assign_blanks.html')
    else:
        form = assign_blank_form
        return render(request, 'assign_blanks.html', {'form':form})

class assign_blank_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = blank
        fields = ['advisor']


<form class="box" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Air Ticket Sales</h1>
    {{ form }}
    assign from:
    <input type="number" name="from_value" value="{{ from_value }}">
    assign to:
    <input type="number" name="to_value" value="{{ to_value }}">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Assign blanks">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `save()` method after assigning a `advisor`. Change your view to:

```
def assign_blanks(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = assign_blank_form(data=request.POST)
        from_value = request.POST.get("from_value", "")
        to_value = request.POST.get("to_value", "")
        blanks = blank.objects.all()
        for b in blanks:
            if b.number >= int(from_value) and b.number >= int(to_value):
                b.advisor = form.instance.advisor
                b.save() # call save method.
                print(b.number)
        return render(request, 'assign_blanks.html')
    else:
        form = assign_blank_form() # instantiate a form for GET request.
        return render(request, 'assign_blanks.html', {'form':form})
```

Also you need to instantiate a form for `GET` request. You are missing **`()`** after your form name **`assign_blank_form`**.

You can further optimize the performance by avoiding calling `save()` multiple times. Create a list of `b.id` in your `if` condition and then use `update()` method. It will update multiple records in a single query. Adding that snippet of code here.

```
blanks = blank.objects.all()
b_ids = []
for b in blanks:
    if b.number >= int(from_value) and b.number >= int(to_value):
        b_ids.append(b.id)
blank.objects.filter(id__in=b_ids).update(advisor=form.instance.advisor)
return render(request, 'assign_blanks.html')
```

Comment: for some reason the form.instance.advisor always returns None even though I don't leave it empty

Comment: I noticed that you are not using your form properly. You are providing post data to your form but not doing anything after that. call `form.is_valid()`. Since it is a ModelForm, then you probably want to save that form with `form.save()`. check for form errors with `form.errors`.